Can spotless be isolated from the application's configuration in gradle?
I have added spotless google-java-format  to an existing project, and a pinned version of guava is causing conflicts.
I have reproduced the problem in a toy example. Here is the full project if you like to reproduce it on your end.
The build.gradle looks like this
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.25.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.spotless'

    group 'com.ahakanbaba'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Beacause of some legacy reasons. The application code needs this
            // exact version of guava.
            force "com.google.guava:guava:20.0"
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        // Lombok dependency
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'

        // Example: JUnit for testing
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    }

    spotless {
        java {
            googleJavaFormat()
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDirs 'src/main/java'
            }
        }
        test {
            java {
                srcDirs 'src/test/java'
            }
        }
    }

    test {
        // Configure test tasks if needed
    }

    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
        }
    }

    application {
        mainClass = 'com.ahakanbaba.java_tutorial.MyFirstClass'
    }

    jar {
        // Configure JAR packaging if needed
    }

    eclipse {
        classpath {
            downloadSources = true
        }
    }
}


Because of legacy reasons, guava is pinned to 20.0 in this project. The application code must use that version. I cannot change that. Similarly JVM is 17.
Running
./gradlew spotlessCheck
results in this error
$ ./gradlew spotlessCheck

> Task :spotlessJava FAILED
Step 'google-java-format' found problem in 'src/main/java/com/ahakanbaba/java_tutorial/Word.java':
'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.buildOrThrow()'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.buildOrThrow()'
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.JavaInput.makePositionToColumnMap(JavaInput.java:315)
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.JavaInput.<init>(JavaInput.java:278)
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.Formatter.getFormatReplacements(Formatter.java:270)
        at com.google.googlejavaformat.java.Formatter.formatSource(Formatter.java:257)


And I think this is due to the guava version pin to 20.0 in the build.gradle. The google-java-format tool probably needs a more recent version of guava and the pin of 20.0 does not have this collect.ImmutableMap class.
Removing the guava 20.0 force, makes the problem go away.
Is there a way to solve this in the build.gradle file ? Somehow separate a different configuration for the spotless checks and run them independently of the guava==20.0 constraint?
I am new to Java and Gradle in general and I am working on adding spotless google-java-format to an existing project. I am very open to suggestions and would love some explanation about the design mindset of gradle.
